# cannot see iAd framework

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, iad

I have created an app with Universal 4.3

I do not see the "iAd framework" under "Link libraries with framework" option.

It only says "Current MAC OS" and not IOS...

What other setting do I need to change, given that I am using XCode 4 ?

Comment: Check your SDK install. It's there on my machine.

Comment: Actually I have the iAd framework showing for other app....so yes iAd framework is not missing...

Comment: @testndtv: I think you can change your base sdk to your latest iOS SDK and that would help you. Please check out my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your base SDK to your latest iOS SDK in your project and target settings and then try again.

I think it should work that way.

Hope this helps you.

If you need more help then please contact me.